# Framer Motion change exit value while it's already rendered

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I am currently using framer motion to swipe between pages in my app. I currently have a function in my navigation bar component that's something like this:

```
const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    const oldValue = value;
    setValue(newValue);
    if (oldValue > newValue) {
      setDirection("-100%");
    } else {
      setDirection("100%");
    }

    // Store the selected value in local storage
    localStorage.setItem("bottomNavSelectedValue", newValue.toString());
  };
```

Basically, handleChange handles the value of the page and saves it in local storage, and I calculate the direction based on whether the new page's index is higher or lower. In each page's code, I've set the div like this:

```
<motion.div
        className="body"
        initial={{ x: direction.direction }}
        animate={{ x: 0 }}
        exit={{ x: direction.direction }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.2 }}
      >
```

In the component's parameter, it's getting the value of direction and the animation is based on which direction I am moving from. This is working on the assumption that I am going back and forth and not going the same direction. So for example, if I am on the page whose tab is all the way to the left, press on the tab to the right of it, and press on the first tab again, all is well. It's because the direction value never needs to change on the exit portion, so the direction is correct. However, if after I go to the second tab and then try to go to a tab on the right, the exit value doesn't change, and the animation acts as if I am going to the left. Is there a way to have the value of exit dynamically change and not be static after render? I added the hierarchy of the code in a poorly made mspaint drawing idk how else to explain it.

[this is the hierarchy of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pZt4.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.